# Disable JavaScript while reading with urllib2

Tags: javascript, python, urllib2

I'm trying to scrape a web page that contains 200+ `<li class="classToGet">` elements, which are loaded with AJAX as one scrolls down. When I read the site's source with `urllib2.urlopen(url).read()` I can only get the initial 100 `<li>`s.

When I turn JavaScript off in my browser and go to the page, all 200+ `<li>`s are displayed. How do I disable JavaScript for urllib2 as it loads the page?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: urllib does not run any JS code.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus What he wants is: he how does the server understand that JS has been turned off because it then sends across the entire content -- and how can he use urllib to emulate that.

Comment: @Thrustmaster: Server has no idea whether the client supports JS or not, and there's really nothing to emulate.

Comment: @Thrustmaster That is exactly what I'm after. Thanks for clarifying and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: Yes, I know that. I was just putting across, in better words, what OP said. And BTW, JS could set a cookie, and server could check for that on subsequent requests.

Answer (score 0):

I thinking you have something to do with http headers User-Agent
I do a small project that fetch pictures from Google picture.
At begin, i used the head as below:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36
```

But, i get the page that work in Pinterest which is not i wanted. Because it's have to get pages. So i changed the User-Agent value to another one:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)
```

Then, it works find now. And it just can give me what i wanted.